# Variables in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I'm tyring to use a variable that I declare in my CDATA later on in my flex document. How can I manipulate "userid" in the CDATA and also send it off in the later HTTPService code?

```
<fx:Style source="felxible_1.css"/>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var userid:String;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>


    <mx:HTTPService         
        id="fetch_list_1"           
        result="listfetched1(event)"
        method="POST"           
        url="find_data_1.php"
        useProxy="false">
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <userid>userid</userid>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>

</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "binding" syntax.  In your script, make the variable send update messages when you change it:

```
[Bindable] var userid:String;
```

Then, in the markup, tell the `userid` tag to update when the variable changes.

```
<userid>{userid}</userid>
```

Comment: You also need to add [Bindable] to the line above the variable declaration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ian Messiter: Sorry, Yes.  [Bindable] is necessary if you want it to update when the variable changes.  Will update my comment.